# Do we get any value for Touch ID For iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, fingerprint, touch-id

My App flow for login is Simple - 
Username textfield and password textfield

I have implemented Touch ID successfully but it has some security drawback like
if user1 get username of user2 he is able to login using Touch ID.

To avoid this I am thinking to map Touch id(Finger print) with Username.

Can I register multiple finger print for multiple username if yes what if registered finger print change or deleted

Is there is any other secure flow for login?

Comment: The TouchID-sensor only tells your app, if the fingerprint is correct or not. You will not receive any information about the finger.

Comment: Do we get any value in response for correct FingerPrint?

Answer (score 1):

No. Using TouchID, you only get the following responses:

> **AuthenticationFailed:** Invalid credentials.
>
> **UserCancel:** User canceled authentication.
>
> **UserFallback:** User chose fallback method, i.e. enter password.
>
> **SystemCancel:** iOS canceled authentication.
>
> **PasscodeNotSet:** User hasn’t set up a system wide 4 digit passcode.
>
> **TouchIDNotAvailable:** Device doesn’t support Touch ID.
>
> **TouchIDNotEnrolled:** User hasn’t set up Touch ID.

[Source](https://www.sitepoint.com/integrating-touch-id-ios-app/)

[Reference Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html)

[Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/)